# How to create an executable using powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way that I can create a simple executable (.exe) using powershell?? a simple one which would open a google page?? also how do I invoke an exe using powershell?? I tried ps2exe code but that was supporting until ps version 4.0, my psversion is 5.0.. Any help on this is really appreciated

Comment: [Sapien Software's PowerShell Studio](https://sapien.com/software/powershell_studio) will allow you to bind PS5 code into an exe.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke an .exe in PS via the Invoke-Expression cmdlet (Also Invoke-Command if you must but Invoke-Expression preferred)
My version of PS is 5.1.17763.134 and ps2exe works in creating an .exe from a .ps1 for me.

Comment: My download seems to not include version 5 so it failed to convert, now I downloaded latest from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/support-for-PowerShell-50-a633de5d with which am able to convert to exe.. will check on "Invoke-Expression".. thanku